# thread runnable? or class? how to run a thread in background?

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player, seekbar

hey guys
I am trying to make a media player in which there is a seekbar.
Seekbar is running with a thread ; this thread is a runnable and not another class.
So far i have added the seekbar and now i want to stop the seekbar when pause button is pressed but there is nothing like :-
myThread.stop or  myThread.pause??

Also i have to run one thread in background since if the user comes back to "now Playing"
activity he can see the seekbar at correct position

Thread is holding me back

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

pause and stop and all those other methods don't exist any more (for very good reasons).

what you want to do is let your thread sit in a loop and do whatever it is you want it to do. Put in some settable flags that you can control from outside that will let the thread exit when you're done with it.

Keep in mind that threads aren't re-usable. Once you have run a thread you can't run it again.

Also, the seek bar can be set to the correct position when the user returns to your activity (I assume you'll keep the music playing in the background).  There's no need to waste resources updating the seekbar's position while the activity is not in display.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [buffering update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnBufferingUpdateListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener%29) callback provided by MediaPlayer?

It doesn't seem reasonable to me to have a thread running in the background to do this.